# App is not taking images from ldpi mdpi hdpi folder

Tags: android

I don't know where I went wrong, but my app is not taking images from drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable.

I developed an app for tablet and then trying to make the app work on phone. Do I created layout-sw600dp as referenced [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). But after resizing when I put my image in drawable folder and drawable-ldpi folder, every time higher resolution folder image is taken , both for phone and tablet.

I have no clue why its not taking from respective folder or where I went wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

!!!!!HELP HELP HELP!!!!!!

Comment: have you mentioned <supports-screens > tag in manifest.xml?

Comment: Ya I did as I commented to Vipin

Comment: the phone and the tablet, some of them the dpi is high, so it will use the drawable-hdpi, if you want to use the no-high drawable, you can try remove the drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: Still, problem is same. Image is taken from mdpi only now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of investigation I came to conclusion that every emulator is of various density i.e. high , low , medium. this can b checked here in image. [image]

That's why my image was taken from hdpi folder. Only solution I found out to use different resolution image for different device, although not perfectly correct. but used this as patch, any answer is still welcome. Thanks

Comment: hey i have same problem of image being picked up by my three 

emulators:240x320_120dpi(LDPI), 320x480_160dpi(MDPI) and 

480x800_240dpi..
i have placed an image with same name as logo.png in my all three 

folder:drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi..
but all three emulator picks up image at drawable-mdpi..
Can you please help me..its been two weeks i have been searching for 

this solution..

Comment: Hi Suraj, As far as I remember when I was facing this issue, problem was the emulator density. Image is picked based on emulator density. As shown in figure, image is picked from corresponding folder if emulator density is high low or medium. Let me try ur config for emulator and will let u know if any progress.

Comment: Yes Suraj, its density only according to which images are picked from corresponding folder. If you look at the ldpi/mdpi/hdpi.... they low/medium/high density pixel intensity...

Comment: hey one more thing..its really making me crazy..
Suppose i have one layout and some images..i want to run that on most of the devices else then tablets..but the problem is i need to make different image sizes and also my components(button imagebutton edittext ...) just varies .. mean to say is that my alignment of components and sizes of image..is there any solution to this..Please let me know... thanx in advance :) .

Answer (score 0):

i think you havent defined it in your manifest add this to your mainifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks but this code I have already added in my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can define drawable folder like

- res
- drawable
- drawable-sw360dp
- drawable-sw600dp
- drawable-sw720dp

for mobile you can put images in sw360dp folder,for 7-inch tab sw600dp & above 7 inch in sw720dp.